# How to execute compiled C++ code outside MinGW bin folder?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

Hi I'm compiling C++ code using MinGW G++ compiler. I've also added the PATH to the address *C:\MinGW\bin;* as an environment variable.

I can access G++ from command prompt and compile the code, but **I can only execute the file if the .exe file is in the *bin* folder**. (I'm guessing it requires the .dll files).

If the .cpp file is compiled outside of bin folder, it is giving me an error:

```
The procedure entry point __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\MinGW\testcode.exe
```

Is there any way I can compile and also execute the code directly from command prompt if it's in other folders?

This is a program that I worked with:

```
// Cpp program to illustrate the 
// concept of Constructors
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class construct
{ 
public: 
    int a, b;
    // Default Constructor
    construct()
    {
        a = 100;
        b = 200;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Default constructor called automatically
    // when the object is created
    construct c;
    cout << "a: "<< c.a << endl << "b: "<< c.b;
    return 1;
}
```

If I compile basic code like "Hello World", it is running outside of the bin folder. But for a bit bigger code like the one above isn't executing.

The compilation command that I'm using is:

```
g++ testcode.cpp -o testcode
```

Comment: Please give a complete example. Basically there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Show your compilation command. You might want the `-o` *executable*  [option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. to `g++`)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf edited

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I am already using -o executable.

Comment: BTW, always compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: BTW, if you are learning C++ or programming, consider installing a [linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your computer since it is much more developer & student friendly (and won't give you such irritations)

Comment: You can use the `where` command to check which g++ compiler is invoked (the first in the result list, if there is more than one result). I.e., `where g++`, outside the mingw\bin directory.